# SharePoint InfoPath formviewer part

Tags: development, infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

I followed the Code

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            XmlFormView formView;
            formView = new XmlFormView();
            formView.Width = ASP.Unit.Percentage(100);
            formView.Height = ASP.Unit.Pixel(100);
            formView.XsnLocation = "Path to form XSN";
            formView.ShowHeader = false;
            formView.ShowFooter = false;

            this.Controls.Add(formView);
            base.CreateChildControls();
        }
```

for showing  the InfoPath form  in a webpart. I am a getting valid InfoPath form in the SharePoint webpart.

But when I follow the same code for showing InfoPath form in the Custom Master page application, I could not able to show the InfoPath form. How can I acheive this?

Comment: I have closed your near identical earlier question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22759.

Answer (score 1):

By default a masterpage does not allow inline code for security reasons and I personally would not change this behavior for security measures.

Your best bet is to develop either:

- A custom WebPart and add it to a WebPart page of your choice.
- A custom layouts ASPX page of your choice with embedded code.
- A custom WebControl and add it to the masterpage of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You might this solution: http://grounding.co.za/blogs/romiko/archive/2009/09/24/integrating-infopath-forms-using-xmlformview-control-with-aspx-pages.aspx. In this solution, the InfoPath control is called via an ASP.NET control on the ASPX page instead of the code-behind.

Comment: I followed this Blog.I am not adding Xmlforview tag (for e.g<Cc1:XmlFormView  ID="XmlFormView1"  Style="width:100%;" runat="server"/>  in Aspx page.But In code behind i have written the Code

Comment: Dynamically In code behind i have written the Code protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        XmlFormView formview = null;
            formview = new XmlFormView();
            formview.Width = Asp.Unit.Percentage(100);
            formview.Height = Asp.Unit.Pixel(800);
            formview.XsnLocation = "http://dev/formlibrary/forms/template.xsn";
            formview.ShowHeader = false;
            formview.ShowFooter = false;
            formview.Hidden = false;
            this.Page.Controls.Add(formview);  
 } Can i know where i am doing wrong ?