# InfoPath form template not displaying in custom  Application Page

Tags: development, infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharePoint InfoPath formviewer part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22715/sharepoint-infopath-formviewer-part)

I have a requirement for opening an InfoPath item from an InfoPath library in a custom application page. Here is the code:

```
XmlFormView formview = null;
formview = new XmlFormView();
formview.Width = Asp.Unit.Percentage(100);
formview.Height = Asp.Unit.Pixel(800);
formview.XsnLocation = "http://dev/infopathlibrary/forms/template.xsn";
formview.ShowHeader = false;
formview.ShowFooter = true;
this.Controls.Add(formview);
```

I am not able to view the InfoPath item but I am getting the view and close button only.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You might this solution: http://grounding.co.za/blogs/romiko/archive/2009/09/24/integrating-infopath-forms-using-xmlformview-control-with-aspx-pages.aspx.  In this solution, the InfoPath control is called via an ASP.NET control on the ASPX page instead of the code-behind.